# php get a list of all keywords from database

Tags: php, list, keyword

I have a huge database containing videos. Each video has a keywords data which contains a keywords about the video seperated by ';' and I'd like to get a list of all keywords in all videos but without any duplicates.

Is there a proper way to get the list?

Comment: There is a proper way to store it originally - in a normalized many-to-many form

Comment: @zerkms that is not a helpful comment, he has the data he has! You telling him it should be differnt is of no use.

Comment: @zerkms is right, db structure's can be changed, a one of script could fix(normalize) this quite easily.

Comment: @Toby Allen: that's why it's a comment not an answer. It makes sense to solve root of the issue, not the consequences. There is nothing wrong in changing db schema sometimes, especially when it makes solving further issues easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pull the data from your database and build an array.

```
//Get Data in Array
$KeywordList = array();
$AllData = getFromDB();

foreach($AllData as $Record){

  $RecordKeywords = explode(';', $Record['KeyWords']);

  //Add to keyword list, overwriting duplicates
  foreach($RecordKeywords as $Keyword){
    $KeywordList[$Keyword] = $Keyword;
  }



}

//This will give you a list of all keywords without duplicates
print_R($KeywordList);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just do a simple query searching the video table and u can use a sifting algorithm.

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM video_table WHERE 1");
$count = mysql_num_rows($sql);

$keywords = array();
$id = array(); // IF Needed to match the video to its keywords.

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
  $keywords[] = row['keywords'];
  $id[] = row['id'];   // Should be the primary key in your db table. on Auto Increment

}

$video_keywords = array();

for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
  $keywords_expanded = explode(';',$keywords[$i]);
  $keywordsExp_count = count($keywords_expanded);  
  for($j = 0; $j < $keywordsExp_count; $j++) {
    $video_keywords[$k] = $keywordsExp_count[$j];
    $k++;
  }
}

$video_keywords = array_unique($video_keywords);

print_r($video_keywords);
```